# tELTPostgresql* usage issue

Tags: postgresql, etl, talend

I'm trying to use tELTPostgresqlOutput with postgres 9.3 server and this is the result:

[image: Error with tELTPostgresqlOutput component]

With a simple tPostgresqlInput and a tLogRow it works perfectly.

Comment: It's failing to create a connection to your postgres dB in the tPostgresOuput component. How have you configured this component? Can you post links to screenshots of each of your components' configuration?

Comment: You should edit your question to include an extra information rather than attempt to provide an answer. I caught the screenshots before your answer was deleted but they still don't show the connection details to your Postgres database. As it is, I've just spotted that your entire approach is wrong as you are attempting to do ELT operations between different database servers and vendors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how to use the ELT components. These should be used to do in database server transformations such as creating a star schema table from multiple tables in the same database. This allows you to use the database to do the transformation and avoid reading the data into memory for your job. It's particularly useful when dealing with large datasets that can't be broken down for the transformation.

If you want to transfer data from one database server/vendor to another you will need to use ETL components (pretty much anything not explicitly marked ELT) to read data out of the source database and write it back to the target database.

In this case you should be using a tMSSQLInput component to read in the data you need, a tMap to transform the data in the way you want and a tPostgresqlOutput component to write the data out to the Postgres database.

Comment: Actually, it was enough to do the work. Hope that it will works for other kind of data transformation.. Sorry for my english i'm a tunisian student and i'm always trying to learn new methods. Thank you very much for your help! :)